# prisma create with nested connect throws error

Tags: javascript, postgresql, apollo-server, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm running into a problem, where connecting a model to multiple items in another model, in a `create` call seems to throw the following error:

#### The error:

```
Invalid `prisma.movie.create()` invocation:
Error occurred during query execution:
ConnectorError(ConnectorError {
user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(Error {
 kind: Db, cause: Some(DbError {
    severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: None, code: SqlState("42601"),
    message: "syntax error at or near \"ON\"", detail: None, hint: None,
    position: Some(Original(93)), where_: None, schema: None, table: None,
    column: None, datatype: None, constraint: None, 
    file: Some("scan.l"), line: Some(1006), routine: Some("scanner_yyerror") 
    })
 }) 
})
```

#### The code responsible for the transaction:

```js
const genresData = genres.map((genre) => ({ name: genre.name }));
await prisma.movie.create({
            data: {
                title: details.title,
                description: details.overview,
                // ...
                genres: {
                    connect: genresData,
                },
            },
            select: {
                tmdbId: true,
                title:true,
                // ...
            },
        });
```

assuming that the `Genre` model has a unique field, `name`.

the bizarre part is that everything seems to be working fine on my local machine but not on the server hosting my app.

Comment: Hi, I'm from Prisma. There seems to be an [existing issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/6803) about this in the Prisma repo that we haven't been able to reproduce. Could you kindly do the following so we can better try to help:  1. Help us reproduce the issue in any way (code that we can run works best).  2. Provide more information about your production server/db and notably how it might differ from your dev setup.  3. Repost your problem as a comment in the issue I linked above so we can take a better look at it/keep you updated when it has been solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the problem.

In my case, there was a difference between the version of PostgreSQL I was running on my local machine and my server.

My server was running postgresql-9.2 while I was using postgresql-13 locally,
so upgrading my server's Postgres version fixed the issue.